# how to make ndb model declarations order independent

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am new to working with python and app engine. I have tried to implement some ndb models like this:

```
class A(ndb.Model):
   some_property = ndb.KeyProperty(B , required=True)

class B(ndb.Model):
   some_other_property = ndb.KeyProperty(A , required=True)
```

of course you wouldn't do something like this in production as it's a very bad design , but it does illustrate the problem.

this code fails because when `some_property` is defined , B is not yet defined.

the question is how can I have classes which refer to each other , regardless of the order of declaration ?

Comment: why would that be bad design?  Seems very reasonable to me.

Comment: that specific case is just for demonstration , in what situation you would need both classes to reference each other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn one of the class names into a string:

```
class A(ndb.Model):
   some_property = ndb.KeyProperty('B' , required=True)

class B(ndb.Model):
   some_other_property = ndb.KeyProperty(A , required=True)
```

Comment: brilliant ! but what if i have to use a static function from the other class ? or a variable ?

Comment: At run time it will resolve to an instance of class B  and you can access all fields on it as usual.